# Ebean return records if list is subset of another list

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, ebean

I am new to using Ebean and needed some help writing a query. For reference I am using Ebean 3.2 with Postgres.

Right now I have an 'Alert' Model that is defined as such:

```
@Entity
public class Alert extends Model {


    @Id
    public long id;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "alert_account", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "alert_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"))
    private List<Account> accounts;

//...
}
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between Alerts and accounts. An alert can contain a bunch of accounts.

I wanted to write a query that would find all alerts whose accounts are exclusively a subset of another account list.

---

Take the following example:

Alert #1 has accounts [#a, #b, #c].

Alert #2 has accounts [#b, #c].

Alert #3 has accounts [#b].

Alert #4 has accounts [#a].

My account list is: [#b, #c]

I want the query to return Alert #2 and Alert #3 since they contain accounts that are exclusively a subset of the account list [#b, #c]

---

I've experimented with the following, but this returned alerts whose accounts match any of the accounts in the subset list.

```
List<Account> accountSubset = //... 
return Alert.find.where().in("accounts", accountSubset).findList();
```

To clarify, the above query has the following behavior:

Take the following example:

Alert #1 has accounts [#a, #b, #c].

Alert #2 has accounts [#b, #c].

Alert #3 has accounts [#b].

Alert #4 has accounts [#a].

My account list is: [#b, #c]

Alert #1, Alert #2, and Alert #3 would be fetched since they contain accounts that match any of the accounts in the account list [#b, #c].

---

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'd prefer to do the filtering in the Data Access Layer, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: `> I am using Ebean 3.2`  
You are aware the latest version of Ebean is 12.1.3 right?  Ebean 3.2 is a very old version.